# not able to enable compression (deflate/gzip)

Tags: .htaccess, compression, gzip, deflate

Since YSlow is still suggesting to enable compression on my site http://www.donboscoeltern.de, I have tried this by including the following snippets of code in the .htaccess-file (listed below are the last 3 versions):

---

```
# 1
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>  
mod_gzip_on Yes  
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes  
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$  
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$  
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*  
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*  
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*  
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*  
</ifModule>
```

---

```
# 2
# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
```

---

```
# 3
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
# Insert filter
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

# Netscape 4.x has some problems...
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
# BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# NOTE: Due to a bug in mod_setenvif up to Apache 2.0.48
# the above regex won't work. You can use the following
# workaround to get the desired effect:
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# Don't compress images
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</ifmodule>
```

---

None of the above versions causes any changes: the tests with gtmetrix etc are all saying that the site http://www.donboscoeltern.de is still not compressed.

Do you have an idea?
Thank you!

Regards,
Vlad Ghitulescu

Comment: Maybe your host is preventing (or rewriting) some of your HTTP headers.

Comment: I've spoke with my hosting company and they are doing this: mod_gzip is switched off for the entry level hosting (that's what I have for this 1-page-only-site). I've got no answer about mod_deflate yet...

Comment: Remember to write an answer to your question when you solved (or found) everything you needed to understand you issue ;)

Comment: I've just did. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the strange behavior - no reaction at all to different approaches regarding compressing via .htaccess-file - was the hosting company: they switched off the mod_gzip-module for the entry level hosting (that I have). Their solution: buy the next level!

Thanks for the hint, cubitouch!

Kind regards,
Vlad